# Illustrator Colour Wheel Settings: How to change the color wheel settings to show a full spectrum?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

The Colour Wheel in the Edit Colors Dialogue Box (see image) is patches of colours instead of a smooth spectrum.

I'm looking to change the settings so that I get the smooth spectrum.

How can I do this?

What am I missing here? Why is the colour wheel showing colour patches instead of a spectrum (i.e. is this based on computer system, the application, the swatches I've chosen, settings in Illustrator?)

I'm using Illustrator CS5.x on a PC.

Thanks in advance for help and guidance as I am very new to Illustrator (but loving it!)

[image: Illustrator CS5 Edit Colors Dialogue Box]

Answer (score 3):

Okay - of course 5 minutes after asking the question (and banging my head against the wall before), I've finally discovered the solution (of course simple and straight-forward!) - so I am posting the answer in case anybody else (i.e. someone new to Illustrator) runs into this.

I had the colour group limited (see red arrow) to 'Document Swatches' - once I changed the setting to 'None' the full spectrum appeared in the colour wheel.

[image: AI Color Editor Color Wheel Settings]